# How can i add and remove Screens from one activity in android?

Tags: android

here i want to simple add and remove screens from one activity which is home launcher activity.

i have on activity. i make this activity as a home launcher. so i want to add and remove screens from here from pressing one button. and want to drag this screens.

For Example Just type Android Home Screen

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager class seems to be the answer you want.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537
refer to above links and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks here i can add multiple screens? i want to make my own simple customize home launcher application

Comment: vote up if you find it helpful.you can use FragmentPagerAdapter,viewpager and Custom views to achieve this.

Comment: Any link there which will help to me to achieve this things

Comment: c attached links with my answer